# Crear urls amigables con htaccess y php

Tags: php, php7, apache, .htaccess

Tengo esto en mi archivo .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Producto
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-z/]+)$ producto.php?var=$1

# Categoria
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-z/]+)$ categoria.php?var=$1
```

Archivo index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>Inicio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="producto/papas-sabritas/10">Ir a Producto</a>
<br><br>
<a href="categoria/frituras/8">Ir a Categoría</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo dos archivos: `producto.php` y `categoria.php`. Cada archivo contiene cosas diferentes y lo que necesito es que el enlace que dice `Ir a Producto` se vaya al archivo `producto.php` y lo mismo con el otro enlace.

He estado buscando pero no he encontrado ejemplos de lo que quiero, ya que todos los ejemplos redireccionan hacia `index.php` cosa que no quiero, si no que lo que necesito es enlazar a archivos diferentes.

He probado con esto y nada

**.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/producto [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=([0-9]+)$ [NC]

# Producto
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{producto.php}/%1\? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/categoria [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=([0-9]+)$ [NC]

# Categoria
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{categoria.php}/%1\? [R,L]
```

**index.php**

```
<a href="/producto?var=10">Ir a Producto</a>
<br><br>
<a href="/categoria?var=8">Ir a Categoría</a>
```

Ahora hice esto y casi he logrado conseguir lo que quiero, que me redireccione al archivo que es:

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

El problema es que no tengo idea de como trabajar los parámetros enviados en la url

index.php:

```
<a href="producto/10">Ir a Producto</a>
<br><br>
<a href="categoria/8">Ir a Categoría</a>
```

Los resultados que quiero son: `producto.php?var1=10&var2="papas-rufles"` a `producto/10/papas-rufles` y `categoria.php?var1=8&var2="frituras"` a `categoria/8/frituras`

Así es como quiero que se conviertan las url's

Después de estar buscando encontré una solución, mi archivo htaccess lo modifique así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3
```

Mis enlaces quedaron así:

```
<a href="producto/10/papas-rufles">Ir a Producto</a>
<br><br>
<a href="categoria/8/frituras">Ir a Categoría</a>
```

Pero me quedo una duda, a la siguiente linea quise agregarle la redirección `301` pero cuando quiero acceder a una página me marca el error `403`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [R=301,L]
```

> ¡Acceso prohibido! Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto
> solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no
> puede leerlo.
>
> Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor
> comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
>
> Error 403

Soy novato en esto de la configuración de htaccess pero como en todos los ejemplos vi que usan esta redirección pues yo también quise usarla pero tuve este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Las rutas con varios parametros en el path deben manejarse con una expresion que permita separarlas. Por ejemplo, la siguiente reemplaza `producto/aaaa/123` por `producto.php?tipo=aaaa&id=123` y `categoria/123` a `categoria.php?var=123`.

```
RewriteRule ^producto/([a-z0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ ./producto.php?tipo=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^categoria/([a-z0-9]*))$ ./categoria.php?var=$1
```

Tomaer en cuenta que las expresiones usadas pueden incluir solo los caracteres de la expresion regular, asi `([a-z0-9]*)` solo puede incluir letras minusculas y numeros, y `([0-9]*)` solo numeros.

Como no queda claro como usas las partes de la ruta (tipo e id) aqui las uso con los parametros `tipo` e `id`. Tu puedes ajustarlo a lo que requiera la pagina, veo que usas el parametro `var`.

Comment: He revisado tu ejemplo pero veo que todo me lo direcciona al archivo producto.php pero por ejemplo: si yo tengo el enlace asi <a href="categoria/18">Categoria</a> o <a href="18/categoria">Categoria</a>, quiero que ese enlace lo direccione al archivo categoria.php y si en el enlace viene "producto" que la dirección la haga al archivo producto.php

Comment: Solamente di el ejemplo de producto, pero puedes aplicar lo mismo a categoria.php, voy a agregarlo de todas maneras al ejemplo

Comment: Agregue las lineas que pusiste y no funciona

Comment: No tiene que ser exactamente como lo puse es un ejemplo, debes hacer los ajustes para acomodarlo a tu caso. Si indicas con ejemplos  cual seria la conversion de una URLs a la version completa con php puedo hacer un ejemplo mas especifico.